# Multiple pageview controllers scrolling

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have two page view controllers inside a parent view controller.I want their controls to be connected i.e. If someone turns page in one, other's page should also be turned to the same index.Thanks in advance for the help.
When someone is scrolling through one page view controller,I am sending the index of  current page to the parent and from parent changing the page of other page view controller as well but there is a lag between both scrolling .How can I minimise the lag or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Please be aware that SO isn't a code writing service - you need to show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what did or didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to implement a UIPageViewController subclass, and then intercept amongst other things [UIPageViewController.willTransitionToViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate/1614091-pageviewcontroller). That way you will be able to respond much earlier to the page turn event.